# My application crashed when I retrieve second time from sqlite database in my running iPhone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite

```
- (void) hydrateDetailViewData {

    strong text//If the detail view is hydrated then do not get it from the database.
    if(isDetailViewHydrated) return;

    if(detailStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "Select name,Rdate,image from Movie_data Where id = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, informationId);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0)];
        self.informationName = str;

        //Get the date in a temporary variable.
        NSDate *date1;
        date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 1)];

        //NSInteger dateInInteger = sqlite3_column_int(detailStmt, 2);
        //self.setDate= dateInInteger;

    //Assign the date. The date value will be copied, since the property is declared with "copy" attribute.
        self.date = date1;

        NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(detailStmt, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(detailStmt, 2)];

        if(data == nil)
            NSLog(@"No image found.");
        else
            self.img = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; 

        //Release the temporary variable. Since we created it using alloc, we have own it.
        [date1 release];
    }
    else
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the price of coffee. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    //DetailViewController.dvObj=
    //Reset the detail statement.

    sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);

    //Set isDetailViewHydrated as YES, so we do not get it again from the database.
    isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
}
```

Second time pointer does not go in if condition & directly goes in the else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my Given Code i didn`t open/close database every Time that`s Why such problem occur to me and some error in type conversion i make mistake as above Chandresh say

Answer (score 2):

Please change your date binding code and you use following code:

```
NSInteger dateValueS = sqlite3_column_int(detailStmt, 1);
self.date17 = (int )dateValueS;
```

where `date17` is `NSInteger`  that is defined in .h file, because I think your date field in database is integer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
//Release the temporary variable. Since we created it using alloc, we have own it.
[date1 release];
```

It should release `data`, not `date1`.

Comment: @AJPatel: was that the answer?

Comment: no buddy their is mistake in my data fetch from int to date thats y my application gona crash